# Can I enforce null safety for platform types from Java API?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin, nullable

From Kotlin version M9, the "enforcing null safety for platform types" was removed.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2014/10/making-platform-interop-even-smoother/

However, I want to make all the java API nullable unless specified as `@NotNull`, so that `!!` or `?.` should be explicit again.

Is that possible in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2):

It is partially coming in the nearest Kotlin release with `@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault`

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-10942